# How to store the JSON data in an array and then display it on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS framework.

I have a `JSON object` returned from a `REST Web API` which has the following data -

```
[6]
    0:  {
    id: 217554043
    todolist_id: 33897822
    position: 2
    content: "Review about percentage calculation suggested by Someone"
    completed: false
    created_at: "2015-11-10T23:06:01.000+05:30"
    updated_at: "2015-12-01T19:07:21.000+05:30"
    comments_count: 6
    private: false
    trashed: false
    due_on: "2015-12-04"
    due_at: "2015-12-04"
    creator: {
    id: 9329381
    name: "Some Name"
    avatar_url: "HTTP://CDN.37IMG.COM/GLOBAL/B3AE8DFCA054A470C4D660D6096934F50010/AVATAR.GIF?R=3"
    fullsize_avatar_url:  "HTTPS://CDN.37IMG.COM/GLOBAL/B3AE8DFCA054A470C4D660D6096934F50010/ORIGINAL.GIF?R=3"
    }
    1:  {
       (data again as above)
    }
}
```

In my script `opendata` is the variable that has the `JSON data` and then I have a controller under which I have the following condition which stores the data from `content:` into an array -

```
if ( opendata.completed == false && opendata.due_on != null ) { 
    var itemName = [];
    scheduled++;
    itemName[scheduled]=opendata.content;
    }
```

In my HTML page I have a `<div>` bound to the controller and then -

```
<h3 id = "newtask" ng-repeat="i in itemName">{{itemName}}</h3>
```

To display the array, which isn't working for me. How do I get this right?

Comment: you need to intialize data on `$scope.itemName ` not `var itemName `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used `$scope` and now it Works.

Comment: welcome..i give answer in the answer section ,so pls accept the answer as i give answer on comment first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the following line is working for you. Mean `opendata.content` has valid data returned from API in Json format.

```
itemName[scheduled]=opendata.content;
```

Than, all you need to declare your variable as global.

`var itemName = []; // won't work`

`$scope.itemName = []; //should work`

`$scope` make it global variable and can be accessed in your view.